# Field salespeople task management

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Will try and make this as short as possible. UTFSE'd (really!)

I need to create a system which has several thousand street addresses, each one assigned to one of several employees. When out in the field, an employee needs to access the address, and change its status (for example, "signed", "not interested", etc.) Management should have an interface for viewing the status by address, by employee, statistical data and so on.

I started programming it all using only PHP, but would love to find a WordPress plugin (doesn't have to be free) which can be customized to do this. A PHP framework (such as Symfony) will be OK as a second option, if you cant think of a WordPress solution.

Comment: Welcome! We focus on custom code here rather than plugins. You could either provide your PHP code and perhaps receive a bit of assistance with turning it into a full-fledged WP plugin, or else check out another resource like a WP Facebook group where plugin recommendations are on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This could be built out fairly easily without a plugin and a little research.  Here is a broad overview of what I would most likely do.

**Use the admin to add/edit/remove data**

- Create a new [custom post type](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/) called addresses (or jobs if that makes more sense)
- Setup [custom taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to hold data about the address (address, status, employee, etc).  Here is an article talking about when to use [taxonomies vs custom fields](https://metabox.io/custom-fields-vs-custom-taxonomies/)

**Use the frontend as your interface for management view the data**

- Create a [template for your custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)
- Pull in and display the data
- I would use ajax to sort and filter the data (status, employee, etc)

Comment: Wanted to thank you all for taking the time (even fixing the grammar!) and pointing me in the right direction. I really, really appreciate it!